# "x Days ago' template filter in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm looking for a filter that turns a datetime instance into 'x Days' or 'x years y months' format (as on SO). Suggestions? Am I overlooking something very obvious?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Have a look at the [timesince](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) template filter. It's builtin.

The following returns a humanized diff between now and `comment_date` (e.g. `'8 hours'`):

```
{{ comment_date|timesince }}
```

The following returns a humanized diff between `question_date` and `comment_date`:

```
{{ comment_date|timesince:question_date }}
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for :)

/me should've read the docs better

Comment: Note that the link in this answer refers to v1.0 of the documentation which is no longer available. The latest is [timesince v2.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince)