# Is there a Django template filter that turns a datetime into "5 hours ago" or "12 days ago"?

Tags: python, css, django, templates, filter

Let's say I have a datetime.  I do this:

```
Submitted on {{ post.date|date:"D. M d, P" }}
```

This actually prints the date.  However, what if I want it to say, "4 hours ago" or "55 days ago" or "2 months ago"?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845009/x-days-ago-template-filter-in-django)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try the template filter [`timesince`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#timesince).

Use it like this:

```
{{ mytemplatevar|timesince }}
```

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATED:**
We can assume that you have a `post_date` attribute saved in your model capturing the time you save the post. `present.time` is the current time that is loaded freshly onto the template when one visits the post. This would be the [recommended implementation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) of what you are looking for:

```
Submitted on {{ present.date|timesince:post_date }} ago.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/412/). It is not built in django before 1.3